# Trying to do form validation on a a meteor form submit with jquery plugin from atomsphere

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, meteor

I want to use this plugin https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate in meteor js

Now when I console.log **`$('form').validate();`**

I get

***`[form.mainForm, selector: "form", context: document, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, toArray: function…]`***

I was expecting true of false then I could just submit the form when the validation is true or false.

Here is my submit event.

```
Template.contactSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var post = {
      email: $(e.target).find('[name=email]').val(),
      name: $(e.target).find('[name=name]').val(),
      question: $(e.target).find('[name=question]').val(),
      found_us: $(e.target).find('[name=found_us]').val()

    };

  $('form').validate();

    post._id = Contacts.insert(post);
    Router.go('acorn', post);
  }
});
```

Here is my submit template 
Note the **`data-required`** in the first input

```
<template name="contactSubmit">
  <form class="mainForm">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input data-required name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Your email"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="name"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="question">question</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea name="question" type="text" value="What do you want to build?"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="found_us">found us</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea name="found_us" type="text" value="How did you find us?"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="submitContact" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the plugin like it should. It expects a valid callback like that :

```
$('form').validate({
    sendForm: false,
    valid: function() {
        // Here is the code you want to run when the form is valid
        console.log("valid !");
    }
});
```

Comment: thankyou. I'll select the answer as soon as I get back home and test :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helps, I tested it at home and it did the trick. I'm there if you are stuck with it.